# Python Event binding on label , Event and binding in differents class

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

My Problem is that i have the binding from the label to his event and the event in different classes but i dont know really how to assign to the label the event in the class.I try it so:

```
class WindowInhalt():
    def label(self):
        label = Label(self.tkWindow, text="What the fuck", fg="black",bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label.bind("<Button-1>", EventsBinding.Test) #here is the assign
        label.place(x=300, y=50, width="200", height="20")
```

And here is the event class:

```
class EventsBinding(WindowInhalt):
    def Test(self, event):
        print("gedrückt")
```

When i start it so i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programme\python\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

If anybody can help me i am gratefull ^^

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the full code

```
#Mein Erstes Gui Python Programm mit Tkinter
#Created: July,2017
#Creator: Yuto
from tkinter import *

#class für den Inhalt des Windows z.b. label
class WindowInhalt():
    def label(self):
        label = Label(self.tkWindow, text="What the fuck", fg="black",bg="lightyellow", font=('Arial', 14))
        label.bind("<Button-1>", EventsBinding.Test)
        label.place(x=300, y=50, width="200", height="20")


class EventsBinding(WindowInhalt):
    def Test(self, event):
        print("gedrückt")


#class für das Window an sich hier wird dann auch z.b. Inhalt eingebunden
class Window(WindowInhalt):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tkWindow = Tk()
        self.label()
        self.windowSettings()

    #settings für das window z.b. größe
    def windowSettings(self):
        self.tkWindow.configure(background="lightyellow")
        self.tkWindow.title("GUI LALALLALALA")
        self.tkWindow.wm_geometry("800x400+600+300")
        self.tkWindow.mainloop()


#Only ausführen wenn es nicht eingebunden ist
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starten")
    w = Window()
else:
    print("Dise Datei bitte nicht einbinden!")
```

Comment: How are you initializing an instance? You just show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you need to create an instance of `EventsBinding`, and then call the method on that instance

```
events_binding = EventsBinding(...)
...
label.bind("<Button-1>", events_binding.Test)
```

If you don't want to create an instance, you'll need to define your method as a static method

```
class EventsBinding(WindowInhalt):
    @staticmethod
    def Test(event):
        print("gedrückt")
```

Comment: @Yuto: this isn't anything unique to Tkinter. This is simply how python classes work.

Comment: Yeah i think about it and than i know it.But on this moment i forgot that i have to do this.